# Pesquisar palavras em ficheiro JSON usando PHP

Tags: php, html, json

Estou criando uma barra de pesquisa em HTML e CSS. Tenho o ficheiro results.json onde todos os nomes de utilizadores estão guardados. Eu gostaria de pesquisar o que o usuário digitou no ficheiro results.json, será que é possível?

**JSON**

```
{
    "name1":"luis",
    "name2":"joão"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Essa variável pode vir de um $_POST ou de outras formas
$nomeBuscado = 'Maria';

// abre o arquivo json
$ficheiro = file_get_contents("ficheiro.json");

// converte em objeto
$data = json_decode($ficheiro);

// seta mensagem defaul
$msg = 'Não encontrado';

//percorre todos os elementos e procura pelo nomeBuscado
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if($value == $nomeBuscado) {
        $msg = 'Encontrado na lista!';
    }
}

// imprime se encontrou ou não
echo $msg;
```

Comment: Seria possível mostrar os resultados encontrados? Não apenas a mensagem de que o item foi encontrado.

Comment: Na verdade, ele está verificando se o nome da variável $nomeBuscado está no json,  Maria no exemplo acima. Ali esta retornando uma string(se esta ou não na lista), poderia retornar um true ou false. A que resultados você se refere?